# Map one video into green screen of another video

Tags: video

I have video which I would like to map to green sceend of another video. Please see pic as example.

**Can you please advice me any software which is capable of doing that?**

[image]

Comment: corner pinning. you can use blender, after effects or any other video editor. see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1e4D1rrBAA

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use AfterEffects and can place the other video inside your green screen.

If the camera isn’t moving in this video then you won’t even have to key out the green. Just place your video on it and scale and match.

P.S You can ask such questions on a video editing site.